# How do airliner pilots practice recovering from a bounced landing?

Tags: landing, flight-training

Other questions say [bouncing an airliner is bad](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/59489/is-bouncing-an-airliner-on-landing-in-high-winds-a-deliberate-technique-or-so/59494), [why bounces happen](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/why-do-aircraft-sometimes-bounce-while-landing), and [how to recover from a bounce.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/why-do-aircraft-sometimes-bounce-while-landing)  How do pilots practice bounce recovery?

Comment: I am guessing that the answer is "in a simulator."  If that's the answer, how is the simulator configured to cause the bounce?  And who does the configuring?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Airline pilots practice *everything* in a simulator, both in initial training as well as every year or so for recurrent training.

A friend of mine is a new sim instructor (and retired captain) at an airline, and he learned to teach this exact lesson yesterday. To ensure the plane bounces, they configure extreme wind shear at a certain altitude above the runway, so the plane essentially stalls and slams into the pavement.

He tried it first at 30ft, and the pilot easily handled the small bounce—too easily, he thought. He then tried 50ft, and the impact was so severe that the sim went “off motion” to protect itself from damage, and the (simulated) plane did not survive. So, the correct setting seems to be somewhere between those two values.

Comment: I am curious what "extreme" means.

Comment: The wind speed used probably depends on the make of the plane and the speed at that moment, to get 'perfect' stall-like conditions and force a bounce.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist True anecdote: we were investigating cracks developing in military jets used for training navy pilots operating from  aircraft carriers. We had no real idea what g forces were involved, so we instrumented a plane and got a flight instructor to perform a series of deliberate "heavy landings."  The guy chickened out at about 10g, so we set the measurement system to record up to 30g. Eight of the first ten landings flown by the trainees were "off the scale" !!!!

Comment: I don't think that a "bounced landing" (and recovery) is specifically included in air carrier training or testing curricula as a required maneuver. Not saying that no one has ever done this in a sim, but I have never seen this type of training.

Answer (score -1):

There is the "bounced landing" button available for the instructor in the IOS of the flight simulator

Comment: Interesting,  what simulator are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to Level D flight simulators

Comment: Can you provide some evidence? What's the IOS?